# How can you disable or turn off the Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14 (Windows 8) touch screen function?

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen, lenovo-laptop

I saw some similar questions here, but they applied to a different model of laptop and the answers they provided didn't work as my settings are different. I tried checking the Device Manager but I don't see any "HID-compliant touch screen" under the "Human Interface Devices" section. I've added a screenshot of the relevant section in Device Manager, but I'm unsure of which entry needs to be changed to disable the touch screen functionality.

[image: A screenshot of the Windows Device Manager, looking at the Human Interface Devices section]

Comment: Look at the properties of each one. What is the listed manufacturer of the hardware?

Answer (score 2):

It maybe under mice and other pointing devices, like in this image:

[image: screenshot]

Right click and choose disable.

It may be worth a try checking the Control Panel.

1. Go to Control Panel,
2. Then Hardware and Sounds.
3. Select Pen and Touch and
4. Go to the Touch tab.
5. Now uncheck the dialog "Use your finger as an input device".

Answer (score 0):

On my Lenovo Flex 2 15, disabling was easy under Device Manager - Human Interface Devices - HID compliant touch screen. Just disabled that and the touchscreen's touch ability was disabled.My screen was broken and this was the only solution to use my notebook without hassle